# Excel - get range of data between two rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have data in following pattern:

[image]

I want a formula to get the data between Content Start and Content End. The amount of content between the start and end is not just limited to 4 and can change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't say what you want to do with this result.

I am assuming you can code the column in which your data is located.

The formula below will return those values as an array. e.g. with your data, the formula will return `{1;2;3;4}`

The values could be numeric or text.

How you want to handle those values is up to you.

```
=INDEX($A:$A,N(IF(1,ROW(INDEX($A:$A,MATCH("Content Start",$A:$A,0)+1,1):INDEX($A:$A,MATCH("Content End",$A:$A,0)-1,1)))))
```

**EDIT**: Here is an example of using that information to create a sparkline.  In this example, the formula above has been wrapped in `TRANSPOSE` and entered as an array formula in `C1:I1`.  The Sparkline has been entered in `B1`.  As with most charts, Excel is ignoring the `#N/A` errors.

[image]

And here is an example where the sparkline is in `A1` and the transposed array is somewhere else, not in view, on the worksheet:

[image]

Comment: I want to draw a sparkline with the data

Comment: @user5155835 Then just output the data into a range of cells, using either the `INDEX` function around the formula I gave you to select each data point individually, or by entering the formula as an array over a  range of cells at least large enough to encompass the output.  If you use the `INDEX` function, wrap it in an `IFERROR` so as to output `#NA()` if you have it in too large a range.  Using the array formula method will do this automatically, but if you want to output the array in a horizontal vector, you'll need to `TRANSPOSE`

Comment: If the content has large number of elements such as 500?

Comment: @user5155835 What was the problem when you tried it?

Comment: I'm getting the range of data. Just the problem is that I have 500 elements. So do I have to select all the 500 cells where I want to get the data and then enter the formula?

Comment: @user5155835 You can do that, or you can use the `INDEX` function (wrapped around the given formula) to pull out each element individually.  With 500+ elements, I'd be tempted to use that method instead of trying to select 500+ cells to enter an array formula.

Comment: You mean entering the INDEX formula 500 times?

Comment: @user5155835 You *could* do it that way but shouldn't. Use a function for the row or column field that would increment as you fill the formula to the right or down, e.g. something like `ROWS($1:1)` or `COLUMMS($A:A)`

Comment: @user5155835 `=INDEX(..formula_above…,ROWS($1:1))` and fill down

Comment: I'm getting #REF! for ROWS($1:2) and beyond

Comment: @user5155835 You probably did not enter it as an array formula with `ctrl-shift-enter`

Comment: Array Formula requires selecting all 500 cells where I want the data. And as we said, we do not want to select all the cells manually

Comment: @user5155835 Not if you are wrapping it in the INDEX function.  Probably you should read about Array formulas so as to better understand what is going on.

Comment: I'm still getting #REF! from the second cell onwards. The formula is: =INDEX($A:$A,N(IF(1,ROW(INDEX($A:$A,MATCH("Content Start",$A:$A,0)+1,1):INDEX($A:$A,MATCH("Content End",$A:$A,0)-1,1)))),ROWS($1:1))

Comment: @user5155835 The function provided answers the question you posed. It returns the data you requested in an array.  Utilizing that data seems to be a new problem, and without more information, I cannot tell where you are going wrong.  I suggest you work on it for a bit, and then post a new question with the formulas and layouts you have tried, and where they have come up short.

Comment: @user5155835 It does not look as if you wrapped the given formula, as I suggested.  Rather you just added a row counter to the given formula.

Comment: =INDEX(INDEX($A:$A,N(IF(1,ROW(INDEX($A:$A,MATCH("Content Start",$A:$A,0)+1,1):INDEX($A:$A,MATCH("Content End",$A:$A,0)-1,1))))),ROWS($1:1)) did it

Comment: Can you help me out to print #N/A in this formula if there's an error?

Answer (score 1):

```
With Worksheets("Your Sheet").Range("A:A")
    Set c = .Find("Content Start", LookIn:=xlValues)
    Set d = .Find("Content End", LookIn:=xlValues)
    ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(c.Row + 1, c.Column), Cells(d.Row - 1, c.Column)).Select
End With
```

Comment: What are you looking to do with the data? Add, Select, Copy, Multiply, Move?

Comment: Draw a sparkline

Answer (score 1):

Probably multiple ways doing this, but if you prefer to do it without VBA you could use:

[image]

Formula used in `B1` (allthough a bit lengthy):

```
{=INDEX($A$1:$A$10,SMALL((ROW($A$1:$A$10)>MATCH("Content Start",$A$1:$A$10,0))*(ROW($A$1:$A$10)<MATCH("Content End",$A$1:$A$10,0))*ROW($A$1:$A$10),SUM((ROW($A$1:$A$10)>MATCH("Content Start",$A$1:$A$10,0))*(ROW($A$1:$A$10)<MATCH("Content End",$A$1:$A$10,0)))+ROW(A3)))}
```

Notice it's an array formula entered through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Drag down....

Comment: What is the use of ROW(A3) at the end of the formula? Content Start can be in any row

Comment: Because I'm using SMALL, we have to tell the function to get the nth smallest value. We calculate the nth by SUM all rows that are smaller or larger than the rows with start and end. We need this amount of rows + three more rows ( hence ROW(A3)) because we need to also take into consideration the two rows with start and ending. If you evaluate the formula through Excel it will start to become clear.